# Navigate between posts from wordpress in Ionic (next/previous)

Tags: angularjs, json, wordpress, ionic-framework

I'm creating an app for my wordpress blog using Ionic, it gets the latest post thumbnail (as my posts are basically a picture per post), I want to navigate bewtween posts using buttons or by swiping left or right, how can I do it, I've searched a lot but I only found infinite scroll method.

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BsMe.jpg

Here's my code: (controller.js)

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])
.controller('LatestCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
$scope.recent_posts = [];  
$http.get("http://haltaalam.info/api/get_posts/").then(function(data){ 
   $scope.recent_posts = data.data.posts;
   $scope.id = $scope.recent_posts[0].id;
   $scope.recent_post_img = $scope.recent_posts[0].thumbnail_images.full.url;
}, function(err){
})
}])
```

(view)

```
<ion-view ng-controller="LatestCtrl" cache-view="false">
<ion-list class="list list-inset" on-swipe-left="" on-swipe-right="" can-swipe="true">
  <ion-item class="item item-image">
    <img ng-src="{{recent_post_img}}">
  </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="row item">
      <div class="col">
          <a class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-right button-ht" href="#"></a>
        </div>
      <div class="col "><button class="button button-clear button-ht icon ion-android-share-alt icon-left" ng-click="share();"></button></div>
      <div class="col "><button class="button button-clear button-icon icon ltr ion-ios-heart-outline button-ht" ng-click=""></button></div>
      <div class="col">
       <a class="button button-clear button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-left button-ht" href="#"></a>
        </div>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: Try with `<ion-slide></ion-slide>`

Comment: The problem is that I have +1000 entry, I cant load them all at once